# Como evitar o erro "warning: ISO C++ forbids variable length array ‘fileName’ [-Wvla]" no C++11

Tags: array, c++11

Eu tenho o seguinte pedaço de código que visa criar um buffer para o nome do arquivo que será criado com base em algumas informações fornecidas na instanciação da classe:

```
char fileName[size];
memset(fileName,'\n',size);
sprintf(fileName, "%s/%s%s-%05u.%s", filePath.c_str(), filePrefix.c_str(), date, this->image_counter++, fileExtension.c_str());
cv::imwrite(fileName, frame);
delete[] fileName;
```

Ao compilar tal código estou recebendo a seguinte mensagem:

```
ObjectTracker.cpp: In member function ‘void ObjectTracker::PersistImage(cv::Mat&)’:
ObjectTracker.cpp:80:20: warning: ISO C++ forbids variable length array ‘fileName’ [-Wvla]
  char fileName[size];
                    ^
ObjectTracker.cpp:85:11: warning: deleting array ‘fileName’
  delete[] fileName;
           ^
```

Qual seria a forma mais elegante e técnica para se escrever tal código e assim evitar este erro?

Estou usando C++11;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dois erros:

1. A linguagem C permite a criação de arrays na pilha de tamanho variável, mas C++ não. Em C++ o tamanho dos arrays alocados na pilha deve ser conhecido em tempo de compilação.
2. Você está dando `delete` para liberar memória de um array alocado na pilha. Isto não é permitido, nem necessário. Objetos criados na pilha são destruídos automaticamente no final do escopo que os declarou.

Se o array for ter um tamanho fixo, definido em tempo de compilação, não é necessário dar `delete[]` nele.

Se o tamanho dele for variável, então você vai precisar fazer alocação dinâmica. Algumas opçoes:

Gerenciamento manual:

```
char *fileName = new char[size];
memset(fileName,'\n',size);
sprintf(fileName, "%s/%s%s-%05u.%s", filePath.c_str(), filePrefix.c_str(), date, this->image_counter++, fileExtension.c_str());
cv::imwrite(fileName, frame);
delete[] fileName;
```

Gerenciamento automático com `unique_ptr`:

```
std::unique_ptr<char[]> fileName(new char[size]);
memset(fileName.get(),'\n',size);
sprintf(fileName.get(), "%s/%s%s-%05u.%s", filePath.c_str(), filePrefix.c_str(), date, this->image_counter++, fileExtension.c_str());
cv::imwrite(fileName.get(), frame);
//Não é necessário dar delete, quando o unique_ptr sair de escopo ele liberará a memória
```

Os dois testes geram exatamente o mesmo assembly, como pode ser verificado aqui em um exemplo simplificado: https://godbolt.org/g/Z1nJ9A. Não há nenhuma perda de desempenho pelo uso do `std::unique_ptr`.

Outra opção é com o `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<char> fileName(size, '\n');//Cria um vector de tamanho size, preenchido com \n
sprintf(fileName.data(), "%s/%s%s-%05u.%s", filePath.c_str(), filePrefix.c_str(), date, this->image_counter++, fileExtension.c_str());
cv::imwrite(fileName.data(), frame);
//Não é necessário dar delete, quando o vector sair de escopo ele liberará a memória
```

Mas nesse caso o código gerado é um pouco inferior.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, foi muito esclarecedora, no caso do vetor acho que seria pesado para o que desejo como pode ser visto no código acima é apenas um buffer temporário que será criado milhares de vezes e precisa ser muito muito rápido mesmo, tanto pelo tempo como sobrecarga do processador (Cortex-A) no caso da segunda opção qualo impacto de se usar o unique_ptr, quais são suas principais características?

Comment: Fiz uns testes e atualizei a resposta. Como esperado, o unique_ptr é uma abstração "gratuita", o código gerado é o mesmo do gerenciamento manual de memória. Já o vector me decepcionou um pouco. Acho que o construtor dele é um pouco complicado demais para os otimizadores.

Answer (score 0):

Em C++ eu faria o seguinte:

```
string fileName = filePath + "/" + filePrefix + date + to_string(image_counter++) + fileExtension + "\n";
cv::imwrite(fileName.c_str(), frame);
```

Uma deficiência do código acima é que o contador não fica formatado com 5 posições. Acho que não existe um jeito fácil e legal de resolver isso em C++ puro, sem usar sprintf, e mesmo com sprintf acho meio gambiarra. Uma maneira sem usar sprintf é esta:

```
string counter = to_string(image_counter++);
string zeros(5-counter.size(), '0'); // supoe que counter nao vai ser maior que 99999
string fileName = filePath + "/" + filePrefix + date + zeros + counter + "." + fileExtension + "\n";
cv::imwrite(fileName.c_str(), frame);
```